# 'Insufficient permissions to access resource': ACL Middleware with Mongoose + Express

Tags: node.js, express, acl

I am trying to set up [ACL middleware](http://npmjs.com/package/acl#middleware) for basic route authentication. In this example, I am just trying to ensure that the user (myself in this case), has the 'admin' permission.

My route looks like this:

```
// define the home page route
router.get('/', acl.middleware(1, '594a984a9815beb8219dca22', 'admin'), function (req, res) {
    acl.userRoles('594a984a9815beb8219dca22', function(err, roles){
      res.send(roles)
    })
})
```

With the middleware, I get the message:

```
HttpError: Insufficient permissions to access resource
```

If I run this route without the middleware, the usersRole() function does indeed come back with

```
['admin']
```

as the response. I can't figure out what else needs to happen for the ACL to recognize me as an admin. I clearly have the 'admin' role.

**UPDATE**

This is the connection code:

```
var dbConn = mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database
acl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db))
```

My config.url being:

```
module.exports = {
  'url' : 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/NodeMongo'
}
```

Comment: It's hard to see what the problem maybe without the acl middleware function definition.

Comment: It's just the vanilla definition from the acl docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl#middleware

Answer (score 1):

The problem had to do with the asynchronous nature of connecting to mongoose. Within the route, the mongoose/acl connection had already been made, but not before that (for example, the middleware function call).

I eventually found the proper way to do it thanks to [this example](https://github.com/ajmueller/express-auth-session) by [Alex Mueller](https://github.com/ajmueller)

Essentially, you need to initialize the acl object from within the callback of:

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function(test) {
  require('./authorization').init();
});
```

Then within your route files, access the fully-initialized acl object. Please refer to the example. It's very easy to follow along.